# python Difference between reversed(list) and list.sort(reverse=True)

Tags: python, sorting

What is the difference between

```
mylist = reversed(sorted(mylist))
```

vs

```
mylist = sorted(mylist, reverse=True)
```

Why would one be used over the other?

How about for a stable sort on multiple columns such as

```
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
mylist.reverse()
```

is this the same as

```
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have hit on *exactly* the difference. Since [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is stable, sorting on the reverse versus reversing the sort will leave the *unsorted* elements in reverse orders.

```
>>> s = ((2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2))
>>> sorted(s, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1), reverse=True)
[(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2)]
>>> list(reversed(sorted(s, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))))
[(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, for general use cases it probably doesn't matter then.

Comment: Right. If you're sorting the whole thing anyways then they'll give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The interesting invariant is:

```
list(reversed(sorted(reversed(data)))) == sorted(data, reverse=True)
```

The other respondents are correct that the difference has to do with sort stability which preserves the order of equal keys.  And also *sorted()* returning a list while *reversed()* returns an iterator.

Comment: An iterator you say. I'm guessing that's one of _yours_ then

Comment: Yes, in fact it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

You get a list for `sorted()` but `reversed()` returns an iterator