# Highest to lowest

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code where I'm trying to find a way to show scores highest to lowest.

But everytime I do it a bunch of numbers come up or it said object.

I'm trying to get the scores from a text file where it is stored.The rest of my code is fine except for this part.

I tried so many ways to the point that I don't realise what I'm actually doing.

```
with open('class1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for f in sorted(f):
        name, *scores = f.split(',')
        hl = list(reversed(scores))
        print (hl)
```

My text file looks like this:

```
nathan ,2, 0, 10 
adil ,8, 9, 7 
masuda ,7, 4, 6 
zain ,0, 0, 3 
abdur rauf ,2, 0, 0 
danniel ,7, 7, 2
```

This is what i get when I run my code:

```
> [' 0\n', ' 0', '2']
[' 7\n', ' 9', '8']
[' 2\n', ' 7', '7']
[' 6\n', ' 4', '7']
[' 10\n', ' 0', '2']
[' 3\n', ' 0', '0']
```

when really it should be like this

```
adil  ,9, 8, 7
abdur rauf  ,2, 0, 0
danniel  ,7, 7, 2
masuda  ,7, 6, 4
nathan  ,10, 2, 0
zain  ,3, 0, 0
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the same `clas` variable for both the class number and the ordering choice.

Comment: You should also use `else if` when the tests are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Where does your `hl` choice sort the students by their score? It's using the same `sorted(f)` as `alphabetical` does.

Comment: Can you show sample file contents? It looks like each student has a comma-separated list of scores. Which of those scores should be used when sorting by score?

Comment: Your code is clear now. But we still need the error message and the contents of your file.

Comment: Im not sur what your trying to say sorry

Comment: after i changed it to this code it became like this      [' 0\n', ' 0', '2']
[' 7\n', ' 9', '8']
[' 2\n', ' 7', '7']
[' 6\n', ' 4', '7']
[' 10\n', ' 0', '2']
[' 3\n', ' 0', '0']

Comment: when i want name given which is then followed by the scores starting from the highest number to the lowest

Comment: What I meant is *What's wrong with your code now? What's the error messages you're getting?*. Also what's `class1.txt` file looks like? Tell us them via [edit] your question then we can tell you how to solve it.

Comment: i used sorted(f) so that the names could be in alphabetical order

Comment: nathan  ,2, 0, 10
adil  ,8, 9, 7
masuda  ,7, 4, 6
zain  ,0, 0, 3
abdur rauf  ,2, 0, 0
danniel  ,7, 7, 2                   this is what is shown in the textfile

Comment: Nahid, welcome to the stack. In the future, this information belongs in the question. That is why Kevin had [edit] in his comment. So you click on [edit] under your question, and place formatted information there. Thanks

Comment: changed it and thank you for your welcome  also trying to get used to the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sorted(f)` gives you something like:

   ```
   ['abdur rauf ,2, 0, 0 \n',
    'adil ,8, 9, 7 \n',
    'danniel ,7, 7, 2\n',
    'masuda ,7, 4, 6 \n',
    'nathan ,2, 0, 10 \n',
    'zain ,0, 0, 3 \n']
   ```

   Note that there's some `\n`, which means new lines.

   **Solution:**

   Simpely use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) like:

   ```
   for f in sorted(f.read().splitlines())
   ```
2. `f.split(',')` gives you (after fix that `\n` issue):

   ```
   ['abdur rauf ,2, 0, 0 ',
   'adil ,8, 9, 7 ',
   'danniel ,7, 7, 2',
   'masuda ,7, 4, 6',
   'nathan ,2, 0, 10 ',
   'zain ,0, 0, 3 ']
   ```

   This doesn't work because there's some spaces behind `,`. Also there's another space at the end of the line.

   **Solution:**

   Use [`re.split('\s*,\s*', f)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), to remove the another space at the end of the line, you can use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) like this:

   ```
   >>> for f in sorted(f.read().splitlines()):
   ...     re.split('\s*,\s*', f.strip())
   ...     
   ... 
   ['abdur rauf', '2', '0', '0']
   ['adil', '8', '9', '7']
   ['danniel', '7', '7', '2']
   ['masuda', '7', '4', '6']
   ['nathan', '2', '0', '10']
   ['zain', '0', '0', '3']
   ```
3. `list(reversed(scores))` can only reverse the `scores` list. you should use `sorted()` here again.

   But since use `sorted` on str object(like `'2'`, `'3'`) will gives you incorrect output. For example `'10' < '2'` is `True`. Covert them to int object use [`map(int, scores)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

   Also you need *Highest to lowest*. Then you could enable `reverse` option of `sorted` via:

   ```
   hl = sorted(map(int, scores), reverse=True)
   ```

   [Here's another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969698/python-difference-between-reversedlist-and-list-sortreverse-true) about what's the difference between `reversed` and `sorted(list, reverse=True)`
4. `print(hl)` can only print that list out. In this case I think you need join them use [`' ,'.join([name]+scores)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

   ```
   print(' ,'.join([name]+list(map(str, hl))))  # covert `hl` elements to str objects again since we need use `str.join`
   ```

---

So the full code looks like:

```
import re

with open('class1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for f in sorted(f.read().splitlines()):
        name, *scores = re.split('\s*,\s*', f.strip())
        hl = sorted(map(int, scores), reverse=True)
        print(' ,'.join([name]+list(map(str, hl))))
```

The output would be:

```
abdur rauf ,2 ,0 ,0
adil ,9 ,8 ,7
danniel ,7 ,7 ,2
masuda ,7 ,6 ,4
nathan ,10 ,2 ,0
zain ,3 ,0 ,0
```

Comment: @Nahid: Well if you think an answer is helpful, remember accept it. Check our [tour] for more details ;)

Comment: sorry but really wanted to know how did you get good at coding so that then i can get good a it too

Comment: Ah, I'm not the best here, try learn more :). And if you got other issues you can always ask them here. But remember, **always ask a clear question**. I suggest you read something in our [help], it looks like I didn't find it. Then: **learn more, ask more, answer more.** ;)