# In Python 3, what are the differences between (stably) reverse sorting and (stably) sorting, then reversing the result?

Tags: python, sorting, reverse, persistent-storage

For example, how do the overall processes in the last two lines differ:

```
alist = list(range(3))
alist.sort(); alist.reverse(); alist
# [2, 1, 0]
alist.sort(reverse=True);      alist
# [2, 1, 0]
```

In particular, is there a possibility of the two methods returning different results, for any other case? If so, what case is that and how might the results differ?

I acknowledge that the responses for [python Difference between reversed(list) and list.sort(reverse=True)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969698/python-difference-between-reversedlist-and-list-sortreverse-true) answer this question. However this question itself is talking about stable sorting in particular. I hope that this question is kept for future users to find.

Comment: I think question is about comparing sorting in ascending and then reverse the list vs sorting with `reverse=True`?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: yes, the "question is about comparing sorting in ascending and then reverse the list vs sorting with `reverse=True`."

Comment: @Ignacio-Vazquez-Abrams: I hope any downvote is not for duplication---see edited question.

Comment: There's a reason that closing-as-duplicate and deleting a question are two separate actions -- acting as a "pointer" for folks who have the same problem phrased in different terms is *exactly* what a good duplicate does, and why we welcome them in the knowledge base. As such, being a duplicate isn't cause for downvoting, so long as a question is clearly asked (which I think this is) and shows an appropriate amount of research effort (which *does* mean that a duplicate shouldn't be overly obvious; I haven't tried searching the terms in this question to say if that's the case here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree, "a duplicate shouldn't be excessively, overtly obvious."

Comment: @Ignacio-Vazquez-Abrams: It wouldbe helpful if those who mark as duplicate would also tell how they determined that it was a duplicate, including search terms used. This would help me to become a better contributor and to avoid superfluous contributions.

Comment: @AnaNimbus, ...I will say that as a fairly long-time contributor, I'll occasionally remember having answered a specific question in the past, and remember enough details to do a more targeted search than might be reasonable to expect from folks who hadn't personally seen the prior incarnation. Thus, a quick close-as-dupe doesn't necessarily mean that a good-faith effort wasn't made -- sometimes coming up with good search terms is *hard*... and it's in those cases where flagged duplicates add the most value, by providing a wider array of searches with a pointer to the preexisting answers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, re: "...it's in those cases where flagged duplicates add the most value..." agreed.